# Create JQuery Mobile button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I need help to create jQuery mobile button using JavaScript, I am using the code below, it creates a button but it is not recognizing the jQuery mobile style.
thanks for your help :)

```
 function SubmitForm() {
    var list = document.getElementById("forMore");   // Get the <ul> element with id="forMore"
    if (list.hasChildNodes()) { // It has at least one
        list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
    }

var e = document.getElementById("services");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var id = e.options[e.selectedIndex].id;
document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = strUser;

document.getElementById("fields").style.visibility = "visible";

var td = document.getElementById('forMore');
var btn = document.createElement('input');

btn.setAttribute("data-role", "button");
btn.setAttribute("data-theme", "b");
btn.setAttribute("class", "ui-input-btn");


btn.style.cssFloat = "left";
btn.style.fontSize = "18px";
btn.style.fontFamily = "myAccountFont";
btn.style.color = "green";
btn.onclick = function () {
    location.href = "/Pin/SendVas?id=" + id;
};


btn.value = "تفعيل";
td.appendChild(btn);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help:

```
var a = document.createElement("A");
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name"));    
a.setAttribute("data-role","button");
a.setAttribute("data-inline","true");
a.setAttribute("data-corner","false");

$(td).append(a).trigger('create');
//Or user parent container:
$("#container").trigger('create');
```